# How to disable themes in bookdown

Tags: bookdown

Bookdown provides three themes (white, sepia, night). In a gitbook authored with Bookdown, one can choose the theme from an icon in the toolbar (white is the default). One can also choose the font type via this icon.

How could I disable the icon so that a user cannot choose a theme?

bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
   fontsettings:
      theme: white

sets the theme but I cannot see a way to actually remove the icon.

Many thanks!